# Best Way to Process Fetch Requests in Parallel with Async-Await in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, async-await, fetch

I'm trying to hit multiple APIs at the same time using multiple `fetch` inside an `await Promise.all` block as follows:

```
const responseData = await Promise.all([
  fetch(
    DASHBOARDS_API +
      "getGoalsByGroupName?queryParamValues=FOOVAL0"
  ).then((response) => response.json()),

  fetch(
    DASHBOARDS_API +
      "getGroupByName?queryParamValues=FOOVAL1"
  ).then((response) => response.json().body),
]);
```

It works great, I'm able to `console.log` the responses.

Now, the problem is that each fetch response has metadata (e.g., statusCode, count) and I only care about the inner contents of `response.json().body`.

If I try that like I did in the second call I make, TypeScript complains saying:

```
any
Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'. ts(2339)
```

**What's the best way to transform the responses so my `responseData` array contains only the data from `.body` right away?** If not possible, do I need to transform each response and then store it in another array?

EDIT:

Forgot to say that I'm using `.map` and a new array to format the data but seems like too much effort compared to doing it inline.

Here:

```
const data = responseData.map(response => response.body)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Body.json()` is asynchronous itself you can't access the body property directly, but you can do it with an extra `then` call:

```
const responseData = await Promise.all([
  fetch(`${DASHBOARDS_API}getGoalsByGroupName?queryParamValues=FOOVAL0`)
  .then((responseBody) => responseBody.json()),

  fetch(`${DASHBOARDS_API}getGroupByName?queryParamValues=FOOVAL1`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseBody) => responseBody.body)
]);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgQQMoAkBCB5BAlOSD6CACgJIwC8MA5EhgLICihpA9FQFDsCmAHgA4gATrFCRYgrhAGQucAIZQ5FGHIDucgJawigkAFsNELgDo5AGzMAKANrsYMAGZcowABaW79mAAMAJAG9EVEwcPGYSAF8Ac2cAcRBzCDQAT1jdAFc%20ADk5PS4AfgBHdK5BZKI5QVyANXMSiHIAMQwMaoQAGQAGb08ASk9jKFcuMEtLCSlwIzQQABNk3ooAPhgJ6Wm55OMAKwhwS17egBpOeycXd097P0DkdCxcAmJImKg0kEyUnLyikrKKqp6WpmepNFptdoARh69n69kGw1G40k6y4i3IKzWUxMu32hwGQxGYyxMhm83RmJR2LJWwARpt%20gBdXoAbnYQA)

Comment: Oh, I see thank you so much. I'm still learning about promises and async-await. putting everything and multiple together confused me! Quick question, is there a way to replace the `.then()` statements with `await` or make it more concise?

Comment: Since these are expressions and not statements, I don't think there's any easy way to use async-await syntax. `(await (await fetch('..')).json()).body` may look like an option, but that would force the fetch to complete before evaluating `Promise.all`.

Comment: Gotcha... thanks again for the help, this works great.